# Where do Plesk 3.5 store backups on CentOS 5.3

Tags: backup, centos

I have a virtual server running on Media Temple that is currently offline due to exceeded disk space. The exceeded disk space is most likely caused by too many backups stored on the server.

Plesk is down, but I can still login via SSH, and I don't know where to find the backups.

Where do Plesk store backups on the server and in what format? (How do I know when they're from).

Cheers!
Christoffer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, /var/lib/psa/dumps is the right location.

Answer (score 0):

I found it by chance after posting this issue, the path was: /var/lib/psa/dumps/1/1/